# adding field to pivot table using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable5").PivotFields(range("hidy!B" & pos).Value), "Sum of " & range("hidy!B" & pos).Value, xlSum
```

Hello I am ading and removing fields from pivot table according to user drop down control. But in above code I am getting error message "unable to get pivotfields property of the pivottable class". I am very new to VBA excel, please help me figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable5").PivotFields(Sheets("hidy").Range("B" & pos).Value), _
    "Sum of " & Sheets("hidy").Range("B" & pos).Value, xlSum
```

The problem is you are referencing the value of cell `Bpos` from `Sheet hidy` incorrectly.
To further improve your code, try passing the sheets to a variable like this:

```
Dim ws1 As WorkSheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheetwithpivot") 'change to your actual sheet
Set ws2 = Thisworkbook.Sheets("hidy") 'sheet with dropdown

ws1.PivotTables("PivotTable5").AddDataField ws1.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable5").PivotFields(ws2.Range("B" & pos).Value), _
    "Sum of " & ws2.Range("B" & pos).Value, xlSum
```

This way, you will avoid `Runtime errors`.